# What is causing this error when I try to use a Compass variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, compass-sass

**application.css.scss**

```
@import 'compass';
$var: 28em;
@media only screen and (min-width: $var) {
  font-size: 120%;
}
```

When I try to visit a page (in development), this Rails error occurs:

```
Sass::SyntaxError at /today
Invalid CSS after "...nd (min-width: ": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was "$var) {" (in /Users/ben/rails_projects/test_app/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss)
```

It works fine if I change **application.css.scss** to use `28em` directly, rather than `$var`:

```
@import 'compass';
$var: 28em;
@media only screen and (min-width: 28em) {
  font-size: 120%;
}
```

Why am I not able to use `$var`?

I'm using

- Rails 3.2.11
- ruby 1.9.3
- compass 0.12.2
- compass-rails 1.0.3
- sass 3.1.12
- sass-rails 3.2.3

Gemfile

```
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
  gem 'compass-rails'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I would advice you to avoid prefixing the manifest file `application.css` . If you would like to add styles , create a new `css.scss` file in one of the `assets` directories and require it in the manifest file . [This guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) has some valuable rules for dealing with the asset-pipeline.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I have only set it up that way to isolate this error. In the actual setup there is no styling in the manifest file.

Comment: Did you try with interpolation : `#{$var}` , it is inside of expression , I think...

Comment: Both variants (with pure $var and interpolated ) seems to pass the render validation on the [sass-lang site](http://sass-lang.com/try.html).Is the scss preprocessor (sass-rails gem) installed OK ?

Comment: Interpolation didn't make a difference. I forgot to include the sass-rails info in the question, have added it, along with some of the Gemfile.